# What happens when a bilingual uses a grammatical subject with a different number system than the verb?

Tags: syntax, minimalism, grammatical-number

For example, Arabic has a ternary number system: singular, dual, and plural. If a bilingual speaker uses an English phrase as a subject that would have dual number in Arabic (but of course the distinction doesn't exist in English), does the Arabic verb take the dual or plural form? Or is this blocked because of the mismatch?

My instincts tell me it would take dual number, but I'm not sure. What is the theoretical account for this?

Comment: can you clarify with an example? Do you mean something like "[in English] his hands [in Arabic] were in front of his face" (obviously with necessary grammatical adjustments for Arabic syntax)?

Comment: @Tristan Sure, that works. I was reluctant to pick a NP with dual number in Arabic because it's been a while since I studied Arabic and didn't want to pick something that wouldn't actually be dual (i.e. is "hands" singular because its "a pair of hands"?)

Comment: I thought that was probably what you'd meant but wanted to make sure. Unfortunately I don't have any particular insight into the matter, but my assumption would be the same as yours that the verb would take dual marking

Comment: Russian borrowed some English nouns in their plural form with singular meaning in Russian, e.g. EN _bucks_ "dollars, pl." was borrowed as RU _бакс_ (baks) "a dollar, sg.", so the word _baks_ needs a singular Russian verb although in fact it´s a plural English noun. {_such singular Russian nouns form plurals by the usual Russian plural suffixes: бакс (baks) "a dollar, sg." :: баксы (baksy) "dollars, pl."_}

Comment: For sure, I think a lot of number changes happen when borrowing, but I'm specifically wondering about code-switching and how those features interact.

Comment: What makes you think it should always interact in the same way? These things are fuzzy.

Comment: @Keelan Did I give you the impression I think they do? I didn't mean to. If you let me know what gave you that impression, I can edit it.

Comment: I think the dual has disappeared from verbs in modern colloquial Arabic varieties.  I imagine code switching between English and Modern Standard Arabic would be a very unnatural process, in which anything might be accepted; however, a dual verb is what the grammar would call for if predicating a verb with a subject corresponding to an Arabic dual noun or two singular nouns.

Comment: @Vegawatcher Ah, I didn't know that, I only studied MSA.

Comment: This seems like it ought to be parallel with many other aspects of code switching; e.g., when switching between English and Spanish, _you_ as a subject would still be expected to be paired with the appropriate verbal form (2sg, 3sg, 2pl or 3pl, depending on whom it refers to and the speaker’s dialect): “Come on, you really no necesita(i)s/necesita(n) hacer esto”.

Comment: I'm just not clear what kind of answer you're expecting. You get the form you'd expected based on the L1, or the form you'd expect based on the L2, or something in between, and for everything on this spectrum it's entirely clear how to explain it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Sure, but the English subject is still base-generated with features compatible with Spanish verb marking, whereas I'm wondering about the situation where the features don't line up perfectly.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I don’t really see the difference. The features don’t line up in either case. English doesn’t distinguish singular/plural or formal/informal in the second person, while Spanish does; similarly, English doesn’t distinguish dual/plural, while Arabic (at least MSA, apparently) does. The speaker of course knows underlying number equally well regardless of language, just like the speaker knows if they’re addressing one or more people formally or informally.

Answer (score 4):

If a bilingual English and Arabic speaker would have to use an English subject with an Arabic verb, it is fully up to the speaker, no matter which language the context is in, to choose which form would be the most appropriate, since there are no rules about mixing languages.

Because Arabic and English are normally not mixed, the experienced "mismatch" is minimal - the main mismatch is the language. For this reason, most people would probably use the dual Arabic verb, since it more accurately reflects reality, and using the plural would create a larger mismatch, so to speak, than the usage of the dual form would.